Clickhouse - optimize when filtering on aggregating columns in AggregatingMergeTree
Suppose I have a table of raw data that looks something like this:
CREATE TABLE raw_table(
    uid UInt64,
    timestamp DateTime64,
    status String,
    ...
) ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (toStartOfDay(timestamp), status);

And I want to create an AggregatingMergeTree. example:
CREATE TABLE agg_table(
    uid UInt64,
    timestamp SimpleAggregateFunction(max, DateTime64),
    status AggregateFunction(argMax, String, DateTime64),
    ...
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (uid);

But now I can't efficiently filter on the columns of timestamp or status.
And this very problematic for me since all my queries are filtering based on timestamp and grouping by status.
Is there any good way to still make such queries efficient and scan the entire table?
